# jQuery .find() doesn't see an element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this template:

```
<script id="work-template" type="text/template">
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body></body>
    </html>
</script>
```

After I try to get `body` element with this code:

```
base_html = $('#work-template').clone();
alert(base_html.find('body').length);
```

But, it returns 0. How it can be?

Comment: It's because the contents of `#work-template` is a string, not DOM elements

Comment: what are you actually trying to do why cloning and then finding the body tag?

Comment: @nurdyguy - It's a quite common pattern for using templates.

Comment: But the issue is that OP is trying to do templating without actually utilising a template language. If you were to put that string into a handlebars or underscore function, it'd work. But basic jQuery only believes it to be a string, not a DOM tree

Comment: It was trendy a little while back to use scripts to hold template text. Not sure why.

Comment: The issue is that once jquery selects an element of type script, the only childNode is text type, so you are not allowed to query the body of a script tag at all, no wonder why you need to do so?

Comment: @rockstar It's easy and requires fewer external dependencies. Script tags because, if you define a non-existent language, it won't parse it or show it on the page. But it's definitely better to do templating in a more structured setup with build tools and the like

Comment: @MattFletcher: What kind of dependencies do you mean?

Comment: @rockstar Well, if you want to load in templates from files (for example `header.hbs`), you'd need to find a way of loading those into your javascript to be later parsed. If you have it in the DOM from the start (even in as a script tag) it's already available to javascript. It's just quick and easy, if not preferable.

Answer (score 0):

The contents of `#work-template` are a string, not a DOM tree. You're trying to access the contents as if it is HTML markup, but it's unparsed.

If you were to use something like [jquery-templates](https://github.com/BorisMoore/jquery-tmpl), you could do what you're attempting here:

```
$.tmpl($('#work-template').text(), {}).find('body').length;
```

Other alternatives would be [Handlebars](http://handlebarsjs.com/), [Underscore](http://underscorejs.org/), and a [whole wealth of others](https://garann.github.io/template-chooser/).

Or, as Kevin says, you could just parse it with plain jQuery and [`$.parseHTML`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsehtml/), but you can't do any extra fanciness with token replacement or loops:

```
$.parseHTML($('#work-template').text()).find('body').length;
```

Comment: That's true. I'll add it to my answer. For most templating cases, the power comes from what values you can send in, loops and conditionals and all that. It depends on what the OP's actual use case is. Ta